# Adding SQL Server CE files in app_data folder at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-ce, orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS with multitenancy enabled. Each tenant has it's own SQL Server CE database in the `App_data` folder. I am creating new tenants by copying tenants data from some other location to the `App_Data` folder while application is running.

Problem is if I click on the tenant, it's `.sdf` is not getting loaded and I get an error

> The page you are looking doesn't exist

If I restart IIS, it starts working. My guess is if we add anything in `app_data` folder while the application is running, this data is not loaded into the `w3wp` process. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Well, it says page doesn't exist. If the program didn't find the sdf, then you should get a SqlCE error or file not found error. It seems like the error is elsewhere.

Comment: but if i restart IIS everything starts working that's why i am assuming it has something to do with App_data folder contents not getting refreshed while application is running.

Comment: Hmmm. I still think the problem is elsewhere. Try doing a File.Exists(path) on the file before accessing to know for sure.

Comment: If it is a permissions issue, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077122/no-access-permission-for-app-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to start off by saying this sounds like a slightly, interesting shall we say, way of doing things. Also, SQL CE isn't really that great for production.

Anyway, I also had some issues regarding tenant creation. Check cache.dat, which holds a list of all tenants, may need to refresh that. I also had to refresh the tenant before it would work:

```
// refresh tenant because otherwise it stays in setup mode
var tenant = _tenantService.GetTenants().FirstOrDefault(ss => ss.Name == name);
if (tenant == null) return HttpNotFound();
tenant.State = TenantState.Disabled;
_tenantService.UpdateTenant(tenant);

var tenant2 = _tenantService.GetTenants().FirstOrDefault(ss => ss.Name == name);
if (tenant2 == null) return HttpNotFound();
tenant2.State = TenantState.Running;
_tenantService.UpdateTenant(tenant2);
```

As retarded as that looks, it fixed my issue.

I'd still recommend building the tenants using Orchard's APIs. Good luck!